Improv over Tennessee Whiskey
I'm playing Tennessee Whiskey. So, the progression is A to Bm. I know there's some pentatonic involved, but should I stay in A pentatonic or should I be switching things up entirely when I go to the Bm?

Have to tried :P? If it sounds good...

Vtc? There will be recommendations, not purely based on opinion, that are as much 'rules' as any other 'theory'. Maybe instead, it's a dupe of some kind?

N.B. This answer isn't necessarily specific to this song, but is applicable to any chords in any song. Merely using this sequence as an example!
Over an A chord, both A pent. min. and A pent. maj. will work well - as testified thousands of times. Over Bm, B min.pent. will work, but B maj. pent will not.
Since it appears the song is in A, You could stick with Am pent. all through, but it would be more appropriate, and sound better, to match the presiding chord. There will be, of course, some notes from A that are the same notes from Bm, and I'll leave you to work out which...
Trial and error is better than an answer here, so use ears, and try for whichever you think sounds more apposite.
From a quick listen, it sounds like the original guitar work uses A pent. maj. on A, B pent. min. on Bm, but that's not going to be a restriction on what can be used.

The double stops in the solo over the first Bm are major 6ths E and C# followed by D and B.  Am I right to read Bm and C#m from those?  The C# seems to complicate the Bm pentatonic idea.

That's not in the remit of the question. No reason on earth to stick to pents, but that's what was asked about. All notes used emanate from key A major, and even on the Bm, those same notes are usable. Why bring C#m into the equation - it's not there in that song.
